# Declaring a private method static

Tags: java, static-methods

Can there ever be a good reason to declare a private method static if no other methods within the class that are `public static` call it?  Even if the method does not require any instance variables, e.g. adds two input parameters together.  Is there any overhead to declaring a method static, which, in a case like this would make it worthwhile to not be static even if it can be run independent of an instance of the class in which it resides?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instance methods have the overhead of having to pass the `this` reference to the method, even if it's not used in the method, so if anything calling a static method is *cheaper* than calling an instance method.

Optimization-wise it doesn't add anything: the method is already private so the JVM is free to inline it if it wants to. Being static or non-static makes no difference.

Design-wise: it's a private method, so you are free to do whatever you want.

Comment: so then that means `private static` does make sense, correct?

Comment: Performance aside, it's also clearer to express that the method is not bound to any instance. But note that this also implies that you cannot override the method anymore (which makes no difference with private methods).

Comment: +1 for "it's a private method, so you are free to do whatever you want". That is a *huge* benefit of private (or package private) methods. I don't know why so many people default to making everything public, "just in case". Refactoring/code evolution is so much safer if you did not expose everything.

Comment: I agree with Thilo: it's better to declare the method so that your intention is clear. If the method is clearly not connected to any instance it makes sense to declare it static; otherwise I'd leave it non-static just to avoid causing raised eye-brows.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons for declaring a method static or not have nothing to do with whether it's private. You can declare it static if it doesn't refer to any instance variables, and some may consider it good practice to do so.